# cant install composer and laravel (mac el capitano)

Tags: macos, laravel, composer-php

im trying to follow step by step how to install laravel via http://www.techonia.com/5369/setting-up-laravel-on-os-x-10-11-el-capitan

but I have error while installing in terminal, here is the logs

> Archievalds-MacBook-Air:~ archievald$ curl -sS
>   https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
>   **#!/usr/bin/env php All settings correct for using Composer Downloading...**
>
> Composer successfully installed to: /Users/archievald/composer.phar
>   Use it: php composer.phar Archievalds-MacBook-Air:~ archievald$ sudo
>   mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer mv: rename composer.phar to
>   /usr/local/bin/composer: No such file or directory
>   Archievalds-MacBook-Air:~ archievald$

I cant even figure out how to install this, any help to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)**:

> Note: On some versions of OSX the /usr directory does not exist by
>   default. If you receive the error "/usr/local/bin/composer: No such
>   file or directory" **then you must create the directory manually** before
>   proceeding: mkdir -p /usr/local/bin.

Hope this helps.